# C# Few issues regarding SpreadsheetLight usage

Tags: c#, spreadsheetlight

1) i am using **SpreadsheetLight** library and i like to know how could i set row's color red or yellow ?

2) also tell me how could i set color range wise say **Range["A1:Z1"]** ?

3) how to apply format cell range wise ?

```
sheet.Range[DataRangeCoordinate].NumberFormat = "#,##0.000;[Red](-#,##0.000);#,##0.000";
```

the above code is devexpress spreadsheet related. so how to do the same when working with SpreadsheetLight ?

4) how to iterate in all cell value with in For loop ?

when i am using dev express spreadsheet grid then i use below code to set back & fore color

```
sheet.Range["A1:Z1"].Font.Color = Color.IndianRed;
sheet.Range["A1:Z1"].Fill.BackgroundColor = Color.LightGray;
sheet.Range["A1:Z1"].Style.Font.Bold = true;
```

5) How to set column width for all column ?

6) How to set **autofit** all columns ?

7) i am getting error when i am trying to create `CreateStyle` 
my code as follows

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;
using SpreadsheetLight;

SLStyle style1 = sl.CreateStyle();
style.Fill.SetPattern(PatternValues.Solid, System.Drawing.Color.IndianRed, System.Drawing.Color.LightGray);
sl.SetCellStyle(1, 0, style1);
```

i have installed latest version of OpenXml from Nuget.

please help me with code sample. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the developer documentation of spreadsheetlight?

They provide an example here: http://spreadsheetlight.com/downloads/samplecode/StyleRowColumnCell.cs

Comment: See this style5.Border.DiagonalBorder.SetBorderThemeColor(SLThemeColorIndexValues.Accent3Color); what is Accent3Color ? I want use color like color. Red or yellow.... How it would be possible?  Provide some code.